Identify user based upon JWT
I have a web application using .NET Identity which is using the standard (cookie based) authentication.
I have a separate controller for a mobile app that uses JWT authentication.
Both of these are set up to be used in the middleware and all works fine.
The mobile app (using .NET MAUI) can open URLs in the system browser. I want to find a way to automatically log the user into the web app (which uses the cookie scheme) when they open a certain page.
My thinking is, if I can open a URL and pass the token in a querystring parameter ?token={token} I can then identify the Identity User and use that to perform the standard _signinManager.SignInAsync(User).
But I don't know how to lookup the Identity User using the JWT string obtained from the querystring.
Something like _userManager.FindByJWT(jwt) or similar.
Any ideas?

Why not as a header?

Using .NET MAUI to open the URL in the device native browser, I can't add headers at that point

So you want to read the token from the querystring instead of the header?

No - I know how to read the token. I can grab that string. I want to know how to take that string and identify the User based upon that token

You want the jwt middleware (which authenticates the user) to use the token from the querystring instead of the header?

The end goal is to automatically log the user into the web app - which uses the Cookie scheme. I can do this if I can identify the Identity User. I want to be able to lookup the identity User based upon the JWT, which will be obtained from the querystring

I'v updated he question to make it clearer

How do you identifiy the user in the JWT middleware? What prevents you to do the same when you get the token from the query string instead of an header?

This code will validate the jwt token using whatever key you used to create it. Then extract the userId from the claim.
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidIssuer = "SomeIssuer",
    ValidAudience = "SomeAudience",
    IssuerSigningKey = GetKey(), // The key used for signing the jwt token
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
};

try
{
    tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);
    
    var jwtToken = validatedToken as JwtSecurityToken;
    var userIdClaim = jwtToken.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "userId"); // I'm guessing here and it will depend on how your token is constructed.
    var userId = userIdClaim.Value;
}
catch (SecurityTokenException)
{
    // Not valid
}


Fantastic. The link i was missing was extracting the userId from within the JWT claim. Thank you!
